# Unlocking KeePassXC for autofilling credentials only

Tags: password-management, keepassxc

As stated in the question, I want to be able to use KeePassXC autofill, but I don't want to unlock the keepassXC DB completely so that changes can be made to the DB itself.

Is this possible in KeepassXC ?

Scenario:
Another user sometimes uses my computer (sibling) for browsing, I don't want him or her taking a quick peek at my DB.

Approach tried so far:
Using CLI, I can unlock the DB and copy the password of a partiular entry to clipboard. This can be done in a single command and once the command finishes its execution the DB gets locked. But the approach is very tedious as I have to always specify the username every time I run the command and cannot take advantage of the autofilling feature of KeepassXC.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Auto-type options.

In KeePassXC, go to Settings > General > Auto-Type. You can set your Auto-Type keyboard shortcut and other things. Among them, you can tick the “Re-lock previously locked database after performing Auto-Type”:

[image: KeePassXC Settings > General > Auto-Type menu with “Re-lock previously locked database after performing Auto-Type” option highlighted]

So, you should keep your database locked. When you're asked credentials, you can use your keyboard shortcut, KeePassXC will ask for the database password, then auto-type your credentials once your database is unlocked and re-lock your database immediately after auto-type.